How can i find Matrix entry that related to the current entry?
In craft 3 / 4 we have this Matrix block to get pages that have the relation field in the matrix
$relatedMatrixBlocks = MatrixBlock::find()->relatedTo($entry)->all();

How can i do this on craft 5 that already use matrix fields ? I want to get any entry that have relation with current entry in the matrix field.
